# Query to see if records start_date and end_date fall in between date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a holiday record that has a start_date and an end_date

I want to do a query where I have to dates '2015-05-05' and '2015-06-05' I want to see which holiday records fall in between these dates and could overlay so for example one holiday record may have a start_date of '2015-06-01' and end_date of '2015-07-10'. I would want that to be picked up in the query

How would you write a query to do so?

Comment: select * from yourtable where date between '2015-05-05' and '2015-06-05'; If you provide your table structure and some test data I will write you a decent query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select * from tablename
where (start_date, end_date) OVERLAPS ('2015-05-05', '2015-06-05')
```

You can find details about `OVERLAPS` on this page: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from tablename
where  
'2015-05-05' between start_date and end_date or
'2015-06-05' between start_date and end_date or
(start_date<='2015-05-05'  and end_date>='2015-06-05')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from tablename
where start_date between '2015-05-05' and '2015-06-05' and end_date between '2015-05-05' and '2015-06-05'
```

Comment: It needs to pick up holiday records where the holiday date range only slightly overlaps not exactly falls in between.
E.g. start_date of '2015-06-01' and end_date of '2015-07-10'